# Проблема с прыжком персонажа

Tags: unity3d

как бы я не пытался сделать прыжок персонаж ни в какую не хочет прыгать в право  в лево двигается а прыгать никак. если что в input mannager на jump стоит прыжок я проверял

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour

{
public float speed = 10f;
public CharacterController controller;
public Transform groundcheck;
public float gravity;
public LayerMask groundMask;
Vector3 velocity;
public bool isgrounded;
public float groundDistance = 0.4f;
public float jumpHeight = 3f;

void Update()
{
    isgrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundcheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);
    if (isgrounded && velocity.y < 0)
    {
        velocity.y = -2f;
    }

    float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
   
    Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;
    controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);

    velocity.y = gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isgrounded)
    {
        velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity);
    }

}
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Если копируешь код, делай это внимательней. У тебя всего две строчки манипулирующие velocity.y, там и смотри. Причём достаточно логики! И даже исправив ошибку, он прыгнет не на ту высоту, если я не ошибаюсь, но это уже другая ошибка.